# TimeSpan.Parse Error

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

```
TimeSpan timeTaken = TimeSpan.Parse("51:45:33");
```

Gives me the error:

> An exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at
>   least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too
>   many digits.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the documentation for [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with single string parameter.
Format for input string is:

```
[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]
```

To make it simple, consider only `[d.]hh:mm[:ss]` part, where `d` and `ss` are days and seconds respectively and they are optional.

- `hh` component is hours, ranging from 0 to 23.
- `d` component is
  days, ranging from 0 to 10675199.

In your case `hh:mm:ss` formated input `51:45:33` has `hh` components equal to 51, that's why you get overflow exception. Days can be up to 10675199, so you need to pick full days from 51 hours, which is two days and three hours.

Resulting code will look something along:

```
TimeSpan timeTaken = TimeSpan.Parse("2.3:45:33");
```

Also notice information about culture-sensitive symbols  `.` and `:`.

To verify answer, you can print total number of minutes

```
Console.WriteLine(timeTaken.TotalMinutes);     //prints 3105.55

Console.WriteLine(51 * 60 + 45 + 33f / 60);    //also prints 3105.55
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Days going up to 10675199 seems a very strange number for Microsoft to pick? Is there any logic behind it?

Comment: @user1 If you check `TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalDays` you'll see `10675199.1167301` being returned. So there is some logic behind Microsoft restriction for days

Comment: I found the answer. It relates to Int64.MaxValue in ticks. I guess the moto of the story is never doubt Microsofts logic

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx

hh  Hours, ranging from 0 to 23.

mm  Minutes, ranging from 0 to 59.

ss  Seconds, ranging from 0 to 59.